# Update Facebook wall with PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a blog system where I want the user to be able to post on there Facebook wall without them having to login to Facebook. I would like it to happen through the PHP SDK delivered by Facebook.

This is the permissions I have given the Facebook application i created:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.mydomain.com/facebook/index/&scope=offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages
```

Just to clarify the permissions: offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages

Below codes only works if the user is logged in. else I get this error:

**FacebookApiException [ 0 ]: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

```
public function facebook()
{
    require_once('facebook/php-sdk-3.0.0/src/facebook');

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $attachment = array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'message' => 'this is my message',
        'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
        'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
        'link' => 'http://www.google.com',
        'description' => 'Test of application PHP',
        'picture' => 'http://www.lalibre.be/img/logoLaLibre.gif',
        'actions' => array(array(
                                'name' => 'Get Search',
                                'link' => 'http://www.google.com')
                            )
    );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);

    print_r($facebook->getAccessToken());
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but how would someone post to their Facebook wall if they WEREN'T logged in?  That seems like an unavoidable precondition.

Comment: I am using have created a Facebook application. That coupled with PHP SDK from Facebook you are able to update the wall of a user. Since the application has permission to update the wall it doesn't seem necessesary that the user also have to be logged in.

Comment: if you have user id, try this `$facebook->api('/user_id/feed/', 'post', $attachment);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to post to someone's wall your application must have wall post permissions for that user. In order to get those permissions the user must login to facebook and grant you access.

For more info: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: If you look at my post you can see that I have granted appropriate permission to the application

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need "offline_access" if you want to post when's the user is not logged in.

Comment: If you look at my post you can see that I have granted that permission to the application